# Angular Input onfocus Opens 'Modal'

Tags: angular

What I am looking to achieve is very akin to what the JIRA website offers as illustrated below:

[image]

I have the nav bar basically done with the search etc and the callback for onfocus working.

When the input onfocus is fired, how can I open a view like the one we see in the picture under the 'Search Jira' bar? It's like a kind of 'pinned modal' under the search bar when the user selects the search bar.

Here is the code, super basic..

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" style="height: 50px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="search-bar-container">
            <input id="search" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="search-bar form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

(No real css to speak of, nor TS thus far).

[image]

When a user selects the 'search' bar here, I would like a 'view', lets say 400px wide by 600px height, to appear under the search bar.
Thanks!

Comment: Hey Daniel, It would be nice if you can post the code or a demo of the output needed so that people here can debug and find the solution for you.

Comment: @m4n0 done there, friend. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You could use (focus) and (focusout) to trigger a dropdown like that from ngx bootstrap.
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/dropdowns?tab=overview